# c program to calculate value of e^x, correct upto 10 decimal places

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop, infinite

I am writing a program that calculates the value of e^x, according to the expansion formula.I need to print the answer so that it is correct upto 10 decimal places. I have tried to do it using, for, while and do while loop , however I cannot figure out where to terminate the loop , which condition to use to terminate the loop. i have written the code as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int factorial(int x);
int main()
{
    int x,n;
    float sum,d_1;
    printf("Enter the value of power :");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    n=1;sum=1;
    while(sum <= %.10f)
    {
        d_1=pow(x,n)/factorial(n);
        sum=sum+d_1;
        n++;
    }
    printf("Answer is %f",sum);
    return 0;
}
int factorial(int y)
{
    int fact=1,i;
    for(i=1;i<=y;i++)
    {
        fact=fact*i;
    }
    return(fact);
}
```

and i am getting the error message expected expression before %.
Please help.

Comment: The syntax error is right where the compiler told you: `while(sum <= %.10f)`  You're trying to use a `printf` format specifier as a floating point constant.  It doesn't make any sense.  Replace `%.10f` with an actual number and the syntax error will go away.  Also, if accuracy is important, you should really use `double` instead of `float`.

Comment: You *won't get* 10 decimal places accuracy fom `float`. Also the `factorial()` function is good only up to **11!** . One way to get 10 decimal places accuracy is to look at the change in value from one iteration to the next, and stop when it is insignificant.

Comment: hi , Tom Karzes, and weather Vane, thank you for replying. since i am  a complete newbie, would you kindly elaborate?

Comment: Specifically i cannot understand which condition i should use to terminate the loop

Comment: Also, you're trying to use the value of `sum` as a loop termination condition.  That only makes sense if you can compare it to the desired final value, which you can't because you haven't calculated it yet.  You need to terminate the loop based on number of terms, or magnitude of the next term, something you actually know.

Comment: Also, if you're allowed to use `pow`, then you could just do `pow(e,x)` without using a series at all.  That's probably considered "cheating", in which case you should ask whether the use of `pow` is allowed at all.

Comment: You are right, and i can just use pow, but I am trying to understand the loops better, that's why.

Comment: If you want to do a power series, then you should do the whole thing inline without any calls to `pow` or `factorial`.  Look up the math for the power series you're using, and determine how many terms you need to obtain the desired result.  Otherwise you're just guessing.  If you just want to know the answer, then look at the source code for `exp` which you should be able to find online.

Comment: ok, I will do it. Thanks!

Comment: Please define (for yourself), what you mean by "correct upto 10 decimal places". This is not easy as surely you are not allowed to use the precise correct value for the definition. I.e. "So that myvalue-correct value < 0.00000000001" is surely forbidden. But you need a definition. How about "MyPreviousIteration-MyCurrentIteration<0.0000000000001". That is (roughly) what @WeatherVane proposed. When you have that definition, then getting the loop condittion right will be much easier.

Comment: For simplicity you could exploit the lack of precision of floating type values. I.e. you can iterate until the value in the data type you chose does not change at all anymore. That way you simply get the value which cannot be improved anymore. Though  I could imagine that for special cases, the iteration will end up alternating between two values...

Comment: I want the answer to be in the form "2.3216549872", i.e , there should be 10 digits after the decimal.

Comment: @Jhilam That's only realistic for a fixed-point representation.  For floating point, you get a certain number of significant digits, regardless of where the decimal point lies.  If the value is large enough, you won't be able to represent any fractional digits at all.

Comment: Probably the best thing to do would be to learn about floating point arithmetic, and how power series work in practice.

Comment: I meant 12! not 11! but one way to avoid factorial (and `pow()`) is to examine how each term relates to the previous term, multipy and/or divide appropriately, and add to a running sum.

Comment: Thanks, I think i understood where the problem is.

Comment: I have a similar question : Find the sum Of series corrected upto 3 decimal places . Can anyone tell how to itarate up to 3 decimal places

Answer (score 0):

You want to terminate the loop when the current term is smaller than some value. Also you want the loop to execute at least once, so a do-while loop is preferable:

```
n = -1;
do {
    n++;
    d_1 = pow(x, n) / factorial(n);
    sum = sum + d_1;
} while (d_1 > epsilon);
```

As mentioned in the comments, there are other issues with the code when it comes to precision and overflow but that is a different story.